# ACL for Web API in Laravel 5.1 that works like a Tree data structure

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, acl

I am a beginner who is working on a web API, Web API must have:

- User management
- Acl (access control list)
- Etc ...

and I do use laravel 5.1 so the question is how do I implement the ACL into the web API using the library or whether I have to make it yourself?

Thank :)

**[Edited]**
I want ACL library that could work like a tree, for example if there is a role `` root`who have children admin` then what can be done by `admin` can also be done by`root` without the need to assign permissions to root enough to `admin`only.

Comment: You can use already implemented package Entrust Package for ACL and role managements. Have a look here, https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: Ths should be a starting point: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own experience the best lib i ever used for Laravel ACL is **[kodeine/laravel-acl](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl)**.

Simple installation, flexible and easy to implement in laravel projects an it's well documented find Documentation **[HERE](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/wiki)**.

Hope this helps.